# Can Elasticsearch suggest missing items of an array?

Tags: elasticsearch, recommendation-engine

Let's say I have recipes that are combinations of ingredients. A lots of them.

```
{"sales_name":"pizza Margherita", 
 "ingredients": ["flour", "water", "tomato", "mozzarella", "barm", "salt"]}

{"sales_name":"kaiser roll", 
 "ingredients": ["flour", "barm", "malt", "water", "salt"]}

{"sales_name":"Sacher Torte", 
 "ingredients": ["flour", "water", "sugar", "eggs", "chocolate", "apricot jam"]}

{"sales_name":"bratwurst", "ingredients": ["pork", "veal", "water", "salt"]}
```

Given a query with certain ingredients: "flour", "water", how can Elasticsearch suggest the most likely other ingredients, by counting them in the documents?
In this example: "salt" appears 2 times in recipes with "flour" and "water", while "sugar" appears only once. 
Therefore the query should result "salt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the aggregations on the ingrediants. As we are already using flour and water , its a good idea to exclude them.

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "ingredients": [
        "water",
        "flour"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "bestMatch": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ingredients",
        "exclude": [
          "water",
          "flour"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! It's more or less what is required. Only thing I had to do  substitute the terms query with something that requires all matching ingredients. Exploring this for a Qbox.io article btw. :-)